# django hosting on apache ubuntu14.04 folder permission

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, django

i am using digital ocean cloud server ubuntu 14.04 apache for hosting.
while hosting i set the permission for the project folder this way:

```
chown -R :www-data <project_dir_name>
chmod -R  760 <project_dir_name> #
```

here i gave the permission to the www-data(group) is read and write. In this case i cant access project using url in browser, but when instead of 760 if i give 770 its working fine. So why need to give execution(770) permission to the project_directory in order to access through url. will it lead to any security issues.
somebody please help me and if the question is not correct , somebody please help me to correct the question

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how things are organised in *NIX systems. Execution permission is needed to "enter" that folder.

Just perform small experiment

```
$ mkdir /tmp/mydir
$ cd /tmp/
$ chmod -x mydir
$ cd mydir
cd: mydir/: Permission denied
$ touch mydir/file
touch: cannot touch mydir/file: Permission denied
```

So without execution permission Apache can't enter that folder and access files inside.

Comment: thanks for you answer. but somewhere i read that , the execution permission will lead to security threat because hacker can inject some script and run on the server.  can you please clarify why it so

Comment: @Thameem: There is a difference between exec permissions for files and for folders. For folders, you *need* exec permissions because changing into a directory is considered "executing it" and you can't do anything in a folder without it. For files, things are different and usually, no file in a django tree should have exec permissions.

Comment: @Sven thanks for you answer. but i have one doubt. here i am doing "chown -R :www-data <project_dir_name> chmod -R  770 <project_dir_name> # " so all files are getting the permission of execute.  so do i want to remove the execution permission for the files.

Comment: @Sven Each Django project has an automatically generated `manage.py` file which is supposed to have exec permissions. Additionally if you develop command line tools for maintenance tasks in your Django project, those should also have exec permissions. But most of the files in a Django project should not have exec permissions. As for directories there is one thing you can do without exec access: `echo dir/*` will work as long as you have read access on `dir`.

Comment: @Sven .. here i am deploying my django project . so what kind of permission do i want to set for the files and folder . in order to make it secure.@kasperd